# What is the core mission of moderators.stackexchange.com?

Tags: discussion

What is the core mission of this site?

Answer (score 5):

> This is a site for people building, administering, managing and cultivating digital communities.

This site is not just about StackExchange sites, this is also about tumblrs, subreddits, etc.